# Conditional method depending on class attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I'm wondering if a conditional method can have his condition on a class attribute.

For instance :

```
class Class1 
{
   public bool _doStuff;

   [Conditional(_doStuff)]
   public static void Stuff() {
      // Do the stuff
   }
}
```

Like the `[Conditonal("DEBUG")]`.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: No, it can't. Which problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: No. Attributes are metadata and can't reference an instance of a class. They must be initialized with compile time constants.

Comment: I'm wondering if a conditional method can have his condition on a class attribute" I guess what you meant was -> I'm wondering if there is a conditional compilation attribute (like the one we use for a method conditional compilation) that can be defined for a class conditional compilation???

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't exist. More to the point, it's illogical.

A method marked as `Conditional` doesn't take part in the build process if the condition isn't met. This decision can't be made in runtime.

The code is omitted as if it was never written and the executable (or dll) doesn't contain that method.

Answer (score 2):

The input of the attribute ought to be a constant. It's used as input for the constructor, at build time.

So in this case it wouldn't work.

If you truly want something conditional, that can be set through variables, I would suggest writing your own attribute class.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

1.)You can do is post compile intercepting the generated IL and remove any unwanted generated IL code.
Look at - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

2.)Use preprocessing tags at class definition and every where you use the class.
For example :

```
#if test
    internal class SomeClass
    {
      public void SomeMethod(){}
    }
#endif

and :
public static void main()
{
#if test
      var someClass= new SomeClass();
      someClass.SomeMethod();
#endif

}
```

Comment: I see i misunderstood your question.
Please rephrase it.

Comment: Did i understand  you correctly , and it answers your question ?