# Method belonging to an object from a class depending on attribute

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

My concern is related to [one question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370427/conditional-method-depending-on-class-attribute), but this time referred to Python language rather than C#.

I am aiming to use the same class to instantiate (two) different objects which share some methods, but not all of them. I came to the conclussion that the most efficient way to do so, *if existing*, might be to add an attribute which could give access to one or another set of methods depending on its value, while sharing the ones that are used for both cases. **Is this actually possible in Python**? If not, how would you recommend me to deal with this issue?

Thank you in advance, and best regards.

**EDIT #1:** I actually have one more small question regarding the use of Factory in this context, related to the use of more arguments and functions shared by the rest of the subclasses. Would this be the right way of defining my problem? Can 'init' and 'sharedFunction' methods be defined separate from the 'factory' one?

```
class Object:

    def __init__(self, serial, np, t):
        self.serial = serial
        self.np = np
        self.t = t

    # Factory method
    def factory(model): 
        if model == 'modelA':
            return ModelA()
        if model == 'modelB':
            return ModelB()

    # Shared function
    def sharedFunction(self):
        pass

class ModelA(Object):

    def function1(self):
        self.t.sleep(10)
```

So that later we can instantiate and use the objects as:

```
>>> modelA = Object.factory('modelA')
>>> modelA.function1()
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

**EDIT #2 (after comment #9)**:
There is still one thing which is not clear enough for me, concerning the definition of attributes within the superclass factory function. Is it mandatory to initialize with specific values or doing so just with the ones provided by the constructor (which is would make sense to me) would do the trick?

```
class Object(object):

    def __init__(self, serial, np, t):
        self.serial = serial
        self.np = np
        self.t = t

    # Factory method
    @staticmethod
    def factory(model): 
        if model == 'modelA':
            return ModelA(serial, np, t) # Here is where I am given an error message. Must I initialize the attributes of modelA and modelB with specific values? Why can't I do so for instance either with self.serial or just serial as I just created the constructor above?
        if model == 'modelB':
            return ModelB(serial, np, t) # Same as above

    # Shared function
    def sharedFunction(self):
        pass

class ModelA(Object):

    def __init__(self, serial, np, t, other_stuff):
        super(ModelA,self).__init__(serial, np, t)
        self.other_stuff = other_stuff

    def function1(self):
        self.t.sleep(10)
```

So that later we can instantiate and use the objects as:

```
>>> modelA = Object.factory('modelA', other_stuff)
>>> modelA.function1()
```

Comment: It's possible, but as stated in the linked answer "More to the point, it's illogical.". Because if a class has some methods and the instance of this class should have access to them. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you need mixin classes?

Comment: Well... For my specific case, I am trying to encapsulate some low-level programming language instructions to a device in more abstract Python functions. The thing is that we have several models of this device, and while they can share some of the already built functions, as they use different low-level programming languages some others will be different. That is why I was asking so. Perhaps one simpler way might be to introduce conditional parameters whithin every of  these methods...

Never heard of mixin classes, so I will have a look into them. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Perhaps an even simpler way would be to write a base class which contains only the lowest common denominator methods shared among all devices, and create specific subclasses which expose more methods specific to specific devices. Then you instantiate whichever class matches the device you have.

Comment: Or you can put the logic not in methods, but in simple functions and have a list/dict of functions related to a specific model of hardware. Then write a proxy method that will be passed name of the function to be called. Or override `__getattr__`.

Comment: Can you comment more on this? I am not pretty sure of whether I caught your point or not. There is one answer below that seems to be also very accurate, so I recommend you to have a look into it!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds very much like a [factory](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html). In its simplest form, it can be implemented in the following way:

```
class Animal:
    @staticmethod
    def factory(kind):
        if kind == 'Cat':
            return Cat()
        elif kind == 'Bird':
            return Bird()

class Cat(Animal):
    def say(self):
        return 'Meow'

class Bird(Animal):
    def say(self):
        return 'Chirp'
```

Now you can instantiate `Animal`s using the `factory()` method which will automatically pick a subclass based on the `kind` parameter:

```
>>> bird = Animal.factory('Bird')
>>> bird.say()
'Chirp'
```

**EDIT:**

It is possible to define other methods in the base class, such as `__init__()` or `sharedFunction()`. However, to make the parent-class attributes (`self.serial` etc.) accessible to the subclass, the parent class constructor has to be called. This can be accomplished in two ways:

1. Reuse the parent class constructor as is
2. Override the constructor in subclasses and call the parent class constructor from it:

   ```
   class ModelA(Object):
       def __init__(self, serial, np, t, other_stuff):
           # Note: in Python 2, this requires `Object` to inherit from `object`
           super(ModelA, self).__init__(serial, np, t)
           self.other_stuff = other_stuff
   ```

In both cases, you have to pass the relevant arguments to the constructor when creating the object in `factory()`. In (1), this means you have to do something like:

```
if model == 'modelA':
    return ModelA(serial=42, np='p', t=0)
```

In (2), you have to provide any extra parameters you added:

```
if model == 'modelA':
    return ModelA(serial=42, np='p', t=0, other_stuff='something')
```

Also not that `factory()` has to be defined as `@staticmethod` in order to make it callable without a specific instance.

Comment: Never heard of it! Many thanks for commenting, I will give it a try to see if it works and will keep you informed.

Comment: One fast question... is this method available for Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, the code should work in both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Hello @Martin, I just edited my code to include my definition. I was unsure of whether I could define 'init' and the rest of shared functions within the superclass body...

Comment: Hello again @Martin. Is it necessary to name the arguments between apostrophes as if they were strings? For instance and following my example as `return modelA('serial', 'np', 't')`. Also, did not understand what you were referring by saying that 'this requires Object to inherit from object'. Could you comment more on this please? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Those were just sample values of the arguments. I updated the answer again in an attempt to make it a little clearer, let me know if it helped. Regarding the inheritance from `object`, see for instance [this](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/python-new-style-classes-and-super).

Comment: Now I understood what you meant! :) But at the same time another question arised. Is it compulsory to initialize the attributes from the superclass while creating the body on `factory()`? These parameters are actually defined for using time, numpy and visa libraries in the methods of each subclass.

Comment: The instance variable `self.t` used in your `ModelA.function1()` is only defined *after* the assignment `self.t = t` in `Object.__init__()`. In other words, you have to call `Object.__init__()` before you can use `self.t`. This constructor is *not* being called automatically when instantiating a subclass. To call a parent class constructor, you have to use `super(...).__init__()` as shown in the answer.

Comment: Already uploaded my question to make it more clear! I did not do so before so I'm guessing there were some misunderstandings about it. Basically, trying to build up my 'factory' method for instance by using `return ModelA(serial, np, t)`after the constructor I am being given the error message: 'Undefined name: serial, np, t'. This is what still confuses me!

Comment: There are no variables named `serial`, `np` or `t` in the scope of `factory()`. The only variables available to this static method are those which you provide it as arguments, plus any variables from the enclosing scope (i.e. globals in this case). Also please note that static methods don't know *anything* about the classes they are members of.

Comment: So let me rephrase it: you MUST initialize every attribute you place in each of the subclasses within `factory()` to make a distinction between each other from scratch, is it?
As I mentioned, these set of variables `serial`, `np` and `t` are just used to handle with `visa`, `numpy` and `time` functions used by `ModelA` and `ModelB` subclasses. If you can't define them this why, should you do it in each of `ModelA` and `ModelB` constructors individually?

Comment: And, on second thoughts, I see another potential mistake in the code I am showing you in my question. Should I define an instance of my subclass `ModelA`as  `modelA = Object.factory('modelA', other_stuff)`, as `factory` method does not include `other_stuff` as argument, I guess this might not work out.